# SFDX Plugin HelpClass is not a constructor

Tags: salesforcedx, cli, help, plugin

I'm building a custom sfdx plugin but getting this following error when calling the command with `-h` param: `HelpClass is not a constructor`.

This happens only when calling my plugin like this `sfdx myplugin:mycmd -h`.

It's NOT happening when I call my command like `sfdx myplugin:mycmd --help`.
Also it's NOT happening when I call my command locally without sfdx like `./bin/run myplugin:mycmd -h`.

Any idea why this behaviour is inconsistent between `sfdx` and `./bin/run` and what can be done to fix this error? Thanks!